# Efficient and concise GroupBy nuisance column pass through

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

**I'm wondering about efficient and concise ways of passing nuisance columns through to the result of a `pandas.DataFrame.groupby`.** I often have columns which I do not want to apply the `groupby` operation to, but I do want the values to propagate through to the result. An example of what I am trying to do is shown below

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
import string

np.random.seed(43)
random.seed(43)

dates = pd.date_range("2015-01-01", "2017-01-02")
types = "AAABBCCCDDDDEEFFFFGG"
rtypes = list(types * len(dates)) 
rdates = dates.tolist() * len(types)

data = np.random.randn(len(rtypes))
info1 = [''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(5)) 
         for i in range(len(rtypes))]
info2 = [random.randint(100,1000) for i in range(len(rtypes))]
df = pd.DataFrame({"date": rdates, "category": rtypes, "vals": data, 
                   "info1":info1, "info2": info2})
df = df.sort_values(["date", "category"]).reset_index(drop=True)

df.head()

  category       date  info1  info2      vals
0        A 2015-01-01  BJWYE    990  0.257400
1        A 2015-01-01  ISQES    475 -0.867570
2        A 2015-01-01  KDEKE    214  1.683595
3        B 2015-01-01  TFOXR    203  0.575879
4        B 2015-01-01  HKTNF    992 -0.399677
```

Here I would like to group by the `category` and `date` and apply some function to `vals` but have the `info1` and `info2` columns passed through.

## Possible Solutions

These are the possible solutions I have found, but both seem somewhat clunky and have quite different performance which made me wonder if there is possibly a more efficient or more concise solution. **I'm applying the `rank` function in this example but am interested more broadly in functions that could return 1 value per group, all values per group or some values per group.**

#### Option 1

Stash all desired pass through columns in the index

```
%%timeit 

(df.set_index(["date", "category", "info1", "info2"])
 .groupby(axis=0, level=[0, 1]).rank().reset_index())

2.64 s ± 47.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

with result

```
sol1 = (df.set_index(["date", "category", "info1", "info2"])
        .groupby(axis=0, level=[0, 1]).rank().reset_index())
sol1.sort_values(["date", "category"]).head()

        date category  info1  info2  vals
0 2015-01-01        A  BJWYE    990   2.0
1 2015-01-01        A  ISQES    475   1.0
2 2015-01-01        A  KDEKE    214   3.0
3 2015-01-01        B  TFOXR    203   2.0
4 2015-01-01        B  HKTNF    992   1.0
```

#### Option 2

Drop the columns and join them back later

```
%%timeit

pd.merge(
    df.groupby(by=["date", "category"])[["vals"]].rank(),
    df.drop("vals", axis=1),
    how="left",
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
)

1.73 s ± 180 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're overly complicating things. You can just `groupby` and `rank` to the `vals` columns. This returns a `pandas.Series` of the same length of your original `df` so you can just set the column to this.

```
df['vals'] = df.groupby(['date', 'category']).vals.rank()

  category       date  info1  info2  vals
0        A 2015-01-01  BJWYE    990   2.0
1        A 2015-01-01  ISQES    475   1.0
2        A 2015-01-01  KDEKE    214   3.0
3        B 2015-01-01  TFOXR    203   2.0
4        B 2015-01-01  HKTNF    992   1.0
```

Comment: That's a good point. This solution seems to address the return 1 or return some cases as well provided I drop the index.